EF Core migration - nullable property gets turned into a non-nullable column
I have a model class OverAllStatus with this property:
[Column("OverallStatusID")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string? OverallStatusId { get; set; }

However, in the ContextModelSnapshot, the column is defined as not nullable:
b.Property<string>("OverallStatusId")
     .IsRequired()
     .HasMaxLength(50)
     .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")
     .HasColumnName("OverallStatusID");

The column is not a PK (I know, the naming is bad, but I have to work with what we inherited). When I try to create a migration, it is generated empty (no changes).
I need to make the column nullable, but I am at a loss. What could be causing this behavior? Is it because of the column name that EF Core expects it to be a key and thus marks it as non-nullable?
I tried to edit the ContextModelSnapshot and remove the IsRequired() method call and generate a migration with the property still marked as nullable. I got a migration that turns the column into a non-nullable one. So basically the next migration would try to revert this manual change anyway.

If it is required, why are you using a nullable string property anyway? Or if you want it nullable, then you need to use IsRequired(false)

Please see this link for help: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25935.

@SoftwareDveloper So using FluentAPI is the only way? It is just weird that EF ignores the nullability of the property in this specific case and marks it as not null, even though it works for basically all other properties.

Is it because of the column name that EF Core expects it to be a key and thus marks it as non-nullable? Most likely. May be some defect, since this is a default by convention, and even if you configure another PK, the requireness set-up by PK convention to remain. So really try explicitly configuring it via Fluent API, because Fluent API has highest priority over conventions and attributes, not sure why you want to avoid it - it is specifically for such scenarios.

Also, you said "The column is not a PK", but is that really true? I mean, not in the db, but the entity model. Because by convention this property is a PK for EF Core, and if it isn't, then which one is the PK property, how it is configured (attribute, fluently)? Also are we sure it isn't alternate key. Many unknowns that cannot be answered without a [mre] - the relevant part of the entity / configuration. I've tried with the current information posted, and cannot reproduce.

What column(s) is serving as the PK for the table? I believe EF convention would pick a property called OverallStatusId as the Key over other convention matches like "Id", so ensure you are nominating a key with .HasKey() or [Key] (Attribute)
